# Comparing date column values in one dateframe with two date column in another dataframe by row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe like this with two date columns and a quamtity column :

```
     start_date       end_date          qty
1    2018-01-01      2018-01-08         23
2    2018-01-08      2018-01-15         21           
3    2018-01-15      2018-01-22         5
4    2018-01-22      2018-01-29         12
```

I have a second dataframe with just column containing yearly holidays for a couple of years, like this:

```
         holiday
1       2018-01-01 
2       2018-01-27
3       2018-12-25
4       2018-12-26
```

I would like to go through the first dataframe row by row and assign boolean value to a new column holidays if a date in the second data frame falls between the date values of the first date frame. The result would look like this:

```
  start_date       end_date          qty         holidays
1    2018-01-01      2018-01-08         23       True
2    2018-01-08      2018-01-15         21       False  
3    2018-01-15      2018-01-22         5        False
4    2018-01-22      2018-01-29         12       True
```

When I try to do that with a for loop I get the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

An answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as all relevant code and data. See: [ask], [mcve]. Odds are you don’t need a loop, have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Shouldn't the last element be false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a fully-vectorized solution, consider using the underlying `numpy` arrays:

```py
import numpy as np


def holiday_arr(start, end, holidays):
    start = start.reshape((-1, 1))
    end = end.reshape((-1, 1))
    holidays = holidays.reshape((1, -1))
    result = np.any(
        (start <= holiday) & (holiday <= end),
        axis=1
    )
    return result
```

If you have your dataframes as above (calling them `df1` and `df2`), you can obtain your desired result by running:

```py
df1["contains_holiday"] = holiday_arr(
    df1["start_date"].to_numpy(),
    df1["end_date"].to_numpy(),
    df2["holiday"].to_numpy()
)
```

`df1` then looks like:

```
  start_date   end_date  qty  contains_holiday
1 2018-01-01 2018-01-08   23              True
2 2018-01-08 2018-01-15   21             False
3 2018-01-15 2018-01-22    5             False
4 2018-01-22 2018-01-29   12              True
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I wish I can buy you a beer...... or twenty :D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def _is_holiday(row, df2):
    return ((df2['holiday'] >= row['start_date']) & (df2['holiday'] <= row['end_date'])).any()

df1.apply(lambda x: _is_holiday(x, df2), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to go row-by-row. But boolean comparisons would be way faster.

```
df['holiday'] = ((df2.holiday >= df.start_date) &  (df2.holiday <= df.end_date))
```

Time

```
>>> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop
```

Quoting @hchw solution (row-by-row)

```
def _is_holiday(row, df2):
    return ((df2['holiday'] >= row['start_date']) & (df2['holiday'] <= row['end_date'])).any()

df.apply(lambda x: _is_holiday(x, df2), axis=1)
```

```
>>> The slowest run took 4.89 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 4.46 ms per loop
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, got the following error:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Are you saying the first solution doesn't work? It should work fine (as long as you have these columns as proper datetime columns - if not use `pd.to_datetime` and convert them).

Comment: yes the first solution does not work and i do not know due to my limited understanding of pandas.

Comment: See if all of `start_date` / `end_date` / `holiday` columns are datetime columns.

Comment: Ive checked, they are all datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try `IntervalIndex.contains` with list comprehensiont and `np.sum`

```
iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.start_date, df1.end_date, closed='both')
df1['holidays'] = np.sum([iix.contains(x) for x in df2.holiday], axis=0) >= 1

Out[812]:
  start_date   end_date  qty  holidays
1 2018-01-01 2018-01-08   23      True
2 2018-01-08 2018-01-15   21     False
3 2018-01-15 2018-01-22    5     False
4 2018-01-22 2018-01-29   12      True
```

---

**Note**: I assume `start_date`, `end_date`, `holiday` columns are in datetime format. If they are not, you need to convert them before run above command as follows

```
df1.start_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.start_date)
df1.end_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.end_date)
df2.holiday = pd.to_datetime(df2.holiday)
```

Comment: This is the only solution that atleast does something. It sets all the holidays as true though. and yes the dates are all datetime64.

Comment: This solution checks each row of `df1` against all rows of `df2` as your description and your desired ouput indicated. Therefore, if somehow every row in `df1` contains any `holiday` in `df2`, all rows will return `True`. It works correctly on the sample data, so I suspect it is that case. Double check each row in `df1` against all `holiday` values in `df2`